# WebApi 2.0 - Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm new to WebApi. Using .NET 4.5 so I guess that's Web Api 2.2

**Getting a Exception : Multiple actions were found that match the request: GetCategoriesById on when browsing to /api/categories/33.**

This works fine though: /api/categories

Also browsing to /api/categories/32/subcategories gives HTtp 404.

My controller:

```
public class CategoriesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/categories")]
    public IEnumerable<MainCategory> GetCategories()
    {
        return null;
    }

    [Route("api/categories/{id:int}")]
    public MainCategory GetCategoriesById(int Id)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [Route("api/categories/{id:int}/subcategories")]
    public IEnumerable<SubCategory> GetSubCategoriesById(int Id)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

WebApi have been restired like this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SubCategories",
            routeTemplate: "api/categories/{id}/subcategories",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Attribute Routing is possible with MVC5, If you use attribute routing you have to use the following way

```
[RoutePrefix("api/categories")]
    public class CategoriesController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("")]
        public IEnumerable<MainCategory> GetCategories()
        {
        return null;
    }

    [Route("/{id:int}")]
    public MainCategory GetCategoriesById(int Id)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [Route("/{id:int}/subcategories")]
    public IEnumerable<SubCategory> GetSubCategoriesById(int Id)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

or

```
public class CategoriesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~api/categories")]
    public IEnumerable<MainCategory> GetCategories()
    {
        return null;
    }

    [Route("~api/categories/{id:int}")]
    public MainCategory GetCategoriesById(int Id)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [Route("~api/categories/{id:int}/subcategories")]
    public IEnumerable<SubCategory> GetSubCategoriesById(int Id)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

If you are willing to add it in routing table you have to provide apicontroller name and action name as well

Comment: Sorry. That didn't work. Still getting Multiple actions were found that match the request: GetCategoriesById. i have tried both your implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Skip Attribute routing and modify route table as

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();   
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SubCategories",
            routeTemplate: "api/{Controller}/{id}/subcategories",
           new { action="GetSubCategoriesById", id=system.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" });
    }
```

The reason is default should be at last.If you put default first it won't check the rest of the code it will go to api controller always inside your api controller you have two get methods. Thats the reason behind the error and you did not provide action name in your route table as well.

Comment: That fixed half of the problem. I don't get the Multiple Actions error anymore but I still get 404 when browsing here:  /api/categories/32/subcategories

Comment: check weather you are getting all the urls in Localhost:your_port_number/help and check weather the detail is provided in the navigation of each url.If you get that correctly the action in controller should get fired